# how to have more than one instance of list item using a class without affecting each other

Tags: jquery

I have written a simple script which behaves like an accordion. However, I would like to improve the code further in the following ways:

1. Is it possible to have more than one instance of the markup below using a class as shown below without one affecting the other because, it does at the moment.
2. Is it possible for a user who is tabbing through to expand a list with spacebar. At the moment, it is possible to expand close and open each list with the enter key?

Code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="main">Test</a>
        <div class="container"><p>More information goes here</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="main">Test</a>
        <div class="container"><p>More information goes here</p></div>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.container').hide(); 
    $('.main').click(function(){
        if( $(this).siblings('div').is(':hidden') ) { 
            $('.main').removeClass('active').siblings('div').slideUp(); 
            $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('div').slideDown(); 
        }else{
            $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('div').slideUp();
        }
        return false; 
    });
});

$('a.main').keypress(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
       if(code.keyCode==32 || code.keycode==13) {
           $(this).click();
       }
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use an `id` attribute instead of class.  The selector looks like `"#theId"`. So you would add

   `id="container1"` and `id="container2"`, or something equivalent to each of the elements where you have a `main` class, and then you would select for your click handler like

   ```
   ${'#container1'}.click(...);
   ${'#container2'}.click(...);
   ...
   ```
2. It's certainly possible.  You would have to register an event handler to pick up keystrokes in the appropriate place (depends on if you want the key press to be picked up if the accordian has focus, for example), and then invoke the appropriate action depending on the key press.

Comment: it depends where you want to key handler to be picked up from.  You could put it on the outer most element of the accordian.  Need to see more of your code to provide  a more clear picture.

Comment: Please see code edit, thats the code i was expecting to use but not sure of how to merge them together

Comment: gables20 that's essentially correct.  I would put all of the accordian dom in a container div, with `id="#accordian-container"` and then keypress on that.